# APS citation style in latex

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, citations, biblatex

How do I use the APS citation style in latex? I cannot find any templates, let alone information if I need to use any specific package or bibliographystyle. Also, do I need bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys

Comment: When using \bibliographystlye{apsrev4-2} i get several errors. How do I change the bibliographystyle when using \uspackage{style=phys]{biblatex} as instructed from biblatex-phys?

Comment: `\bibliographystlye` is a command for bibtex. You need to use biblatex syntax instead. I posted a short example below. Don't forget to compile with biber instead of bibtex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short example using the `phys` style from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    style=phys,%
    articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
    chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false%
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

test \cite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no need for \bibliographystyle? The documentation says that style follows the revtex class, which is where I found e.g. "apsrev4-2. Can I use \usepackage[style=apsrev4-2]{biblatex}?

Comment: No, `\bibliographystyle` is for bibtex, not biblatex

Comment: And no again, `apsrev4-2` is not a biblatex style

Comment: I understand. "Follows the revtex class" means that it is already implemented. My bad! Sorry and thank you!